# Updating CiviCRM Module in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Here is what happened...

I was doing an update to CiviCRM (through the recommended process) from .10 to .15.

After I copied the files over, I was getting a 500.

So I checked the log and I was getting an error message:

Notice: Constant CIVICRM_MEMCACHE_PREFIX already defined in include_once() (line 310 of /home3/isrcus/public_html/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php).

and the next one:

Deprecated function: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; backup_file has a deprecated constructor in require_once() (line 279 of /home3/isrcus/public_html/sites/all/modules/backup_migrate/backup_migrate.module).

Why am I getting those error messages?

Thanks!
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what settings you have for `CIVICRM_MEMCACHE_PREFIX` in your civicrm.settings.php file. You can't define a constant more than once.  Maybe copy/paste the relevant sections into your question.  Don't include the whole file.

The 'Deprecated function' relates to the Drupal backup_migrate module - nothing to to do with CiviCRM.  Have you just changed php version?  That message relates to a changes [introduced in php 7](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php)  Make sure your Drupal modules are updated.